# Is it possible to force a scale on geom_raster()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to compare three plots using `geom_raster()`. The problem is that I would like to maintain the same scale in all three plots that was set in the first plot [-3,3].

Here is my code:

```
#raster plots
box <- .05
df <- expand.grid(x1 = seq(-1, 1, box), x2 = seq(-1, 1, box))
df$risk <- df$x1 + 2*df$x2

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2, fill = risk)) + geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFFFFF","#046380","#000000")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("True Risk")

df <- expand.grid(x1 = seq(-1, 1, box), x2 = seq(-1, 1, box))
df$risk <- .99*df$x1 + 1.98*df$x2

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2, fill = risk)) + geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFFFFF","#046380","#000000")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Estimated Risk")

df <- expand.grid(x1 = seq(-1, 1, box), x2 = seq(-1, 1, box))
df$risk <- .01*df$x1 + .02*df$x2
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2, fill = risk)) + geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFFFFF","#046380","#000000")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Difference")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=1)
```

This is my output

[image]

It is hard to see that the difference is minimal because the scale changes to [0.03, -0.03]. How can I show the correct surface, but on the original scale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep all the three variables in one `data.frame` and use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` to maintain the scale.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
box <- .05
df <- expand.grid(x1 = seq(-1, 1, box), x2 = seq(-1, 1, box))
# Calculate each field
df$TrueRisk <- df$x1 + 2*df$x2
df$EstimatedRisk <- .99*df$x1 + 1.98*df$x2
df$Difference <- .01*df$x1 + .02*df$x2

# Transform the data into long format for ggplot2
df <- melt(df, c("x1", "x2"))

# Use facet_grid/facet_wrap to create the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2, fill = value)) + geom_raster() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFFFFF","#046380","#000000")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Risk")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! You can leverage the `expand.grid` to make the extra rows: `grps <- c('True Risk', 'Estimated Risk', 'Difference');

df <- expand.grid(x1 = seq(-1, 1, box), 
                  x2 = seq(-1, 1, box), 
                  group = factor(grps, levels = grps));

groups <- data.frame(group = grps, 
                     v1 = c(1, .99, .01), 
                     v2 = c(2, 1.98, .02));

df <- merge(df, groups);
df$risk <- df$v1 * df$x1 + df$v2 * df$x2; ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2, fill = risk)) + 
    geom_raster() +
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1)`